# Cross Tab query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, pivot, crosstab

I have a SQL table with following fields

```
ID, Rly, Shed, Loco_no, shed, Date_failure, Equipt
```

I am using a cross tab query in access using the following script in MS Access 2007

```
TRANSFORM Count(Sheet1.[sno]) AS CountOfsno
SELECT Sheet1.[Equipt], Count(Sheet1.[sno]) AS [Total Of sno]
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY Sheet1.[Equipt]
PIVOT Sheet1.[Shed];
```

How can this query be converted to a SQL Server stored procedure for use on an aspx page?

please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL equivalent of an MS Access Crosstab query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802630/tsql-equivalent-of-an-ms-access-crosstab-query)

Comment: Search also for Pivot in the SQL Server tag.

Comment: I have tried above mentioned example as : SELECT Equipt, [BSL] AS BSL, [AQ] AS AQ

FROM (SELECT Equipt, Shed 

FROM PunctualityMain) ps


PIVOT 
(COUNT (Equipt)
FOR Equipt IN ([BSL], [AQ])) AS pvt But it generate an error as : Invalid column name 'Equipt'.

Comment: @user1235981 if you post some sample data that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you will want to look at the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.  Considering you did not provide many details on your table or sample data, based on your attempt in the comments something like this might point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Equipt, Shed
    FROM PunctualityMain
) x
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(Equipt)
    FOR Shed IN ([BSL], [AQ])
) p
```

If you post some more details, then we could provide additional help.

Comment: 1st Filed 'Equipt' data  - TFP, TM, VCD, VCB, Gear, Bogie and 2nd Field 'Shed' data - BSL, AQ, TKD, AJJ, GZB, NKJ.  Requirement is counting of Equipt in Shed like 22 TM in Shed BSL or 5 TFP in Shed AJJ.

Comment: Thanks for Ans above but name of eqipt are missing. Req. is TFP 5 in BSL, 2 in AQ; VCD 8 in BSL, 1 in AQ etc.

Comment: Please edit your OP with some sample data from your table as well as the expected result. Please include all fields that you need to have in your final product.

Comment: I have modified your ans as per my requirement and it works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Equip     BSL      AQ                                               TFP 0 3
TM 4 0
VCB 1 1
VCD 5 0   Here is the result. Can a total field also be added at end of each row like                            Equipt    BSL   AQ   Total

Comment: putting the sample data in the comments is not helpful, please edit your original question and place the data there.